# Control initial speed and the length of rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript

While it does work, the calculated rotation ends painstakingly slow; it seems that I can have control of the speed of the rotation's start or the duration of the entire rotation, but not both. Ideally, I would like control over the initial speed and the length of the rotation, but at the moment, that's not possible.

[Here is a link to the minimalist demo scene.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5-QbIxsqFgRfktSWHBHNm1wSk9EZ1N2V216ZjhNU254VmRHcXBrS3dIc1g0R2xVOGJDRUE&usp=sharing)

```
var rb1: Rigidbody;// cube
var rb2: Rigidbody;// wheel
var DeactivateDelay : float;
var SpeedUpperLimit : float;
var wheel: GameObject;

private var nf2 = 0.0;
private var nf3 = 0.0;
private var Touched = false;
private var TouchedOLD = false;
private var x;
private var isSpinning = false;
private var direction = false;
private var directionOLD = false;
private var speed = 0.0;
private var speedvect = new Vector3();
private var startPos = 0.0;
private var nowPos = 0.0;
private var OriginalTouchedTime = 0.0;
private var startTime = 0.0;
private var stopTime = 0.0;
private var nowTime = 0.0;
private var timeDiff = 0.0;
private var mouseY = 0.0;
private var t2old = 0.0;
private var t2new = 0.0;
private var cYold = 0.0;
private var cYnew = 0.0;
private var directionDegreeMultiplier = 1.0;
private var q1 = new Quaternion();
private var q2 = new Quaternion();
private var angle = 0.0;
private var currentAngle = 0.0;
private var nf = "open";

InvokeRepeating("startCheckingSpeed", 1, 0.1);// check speed every tenth of a second
function startCheckingSpeed () {
    cYold = cYnew; // save old y coordinate to measure against
    cYnew = nf2*-7.5; // calc new y coord
    t2old = t2new; // save old time
    t2new = Time.time; // get new time

    if(cYold > cYnew){//the swipe is moving down
    speed = (cYnew-cYold)/(t2old-t2new);
    directionDegreeMultiplier = 1.0;
    }
    if(cYold < cYnew){//the swipe is moving up
    speed = (cYold-cYnew)/(t2old-t2new);
    directionDegreeMultiplier = -1.0;
    }
    if(float.IsNaN(speed)||cYold==cYnew){speed=0.0;}// incase of garbage and none motion
    if(speed > SpeedUpperLimit){speed=SpeedUpperLimit;}// set limits to avoid insanity???
}

function FixedUpdate () {

TouchedOLD = Touched; // save previous touch state

if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){ // beter than onMouseDown events
Touched = true;
var nf = (Input.mousePosition.y / Screen.height).ToString(); 
}else{
Touched = false;
nf = "over";
}

// get the string from the bluetooth connection.
// parse it, its normalized Y coordinates...
// subtract 0.5 to give us center
// multiply by 7.5 , dunno why...just works better???
if(nf=="open"||nf=="began"||nf=="over"||nf==""){Touched=false;mouseY = 0.0;nf2=0.0;}else{Touched=true;nf2=parseFloat(nf);nf3=nf2-0.5;mouseY = nf3*7.5;}

if(TouchedOLD != Touched){
    if(Touched){
        rb1.isKinematic = false;//turn on physics for hinge
        rb2.isKinematic = false;//turn on physics for hinge

        iTween.Stop(); // kill any current iTweens
    }else{
        rb1.isKinematic = true;//turn off physics for free spin
        rb2.isKinematic = true;//turn off physics for free spin
        Debug.Log("-----TOUCH-OFF------");
        iTween.RotateTo(wheel,{"rotation":Vector3(0, 0, (1080*directionDegreeMultiplier)),  "speed":speed, "transition":"linear"});// <---------THIS WORKS---------

    }   
}


    x = Mathf.Pow(4,2) - Mathf.Pow(mouseY,2); // B^2 = C^2 - A^2
    x = Mathf.Sqrt(x);// set x coord to make the arc, greater range of motion

    if(float.IsNaN(x)){x=-2.5;}// just incase i get garbage...
    // move the outer cube, hinged to center cube to create grab and pull effect...is there a better way?
    rb1.position = Vector3(x,mouseY,25); 



}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Ideally, I would like control over the initial speed and the length of the rotation